# Update textarea after get response from servlet in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, synchronous

I have a program which calls a function in javascript with 1 o more requests to 1 servlet, I want to execute request after request and get the response after each exucution, to make this I have 1 function, but it only shows the result after all requests  have been executed.

```
function cmd(args) {
    width = 0;
    var res = args.split('\n');
    var largo = res.length;
    var progressLength = 100 / largo;
    for (var i = 0; i < largo; i++)
    {
        if (res[i] == 'desconectar')
        {
            desconectar();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            executeCMD(res[i]);

        }
    }
}
function executeCMD(args)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Controlador',
        data: {cmd: args, operacion: 1},
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById('respuesta').value = document.getElementById('respuesta').value + response;
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false
    });
}
```

If I add window.alert(response); inside success field it shows the progress step by step and works fine, but it show alerts which I don't want.

This is I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtaMI.jpg but I'm getting only last picture.

Comment: Is there any reason you have `async: false`? This is generally considered bad practice, and is even [deprecated in jQuery 1.8+](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Yes, if I set async as true, the requests will be displayed after end my loop from where I call the function execute CMD. So the response will be displayed at the same time.

Comment: Not sure but I think the problem might also be the `progress` variable. How do you set it? Is this current value to set in progress bar or callback function?

Comment: You can delete that line, it's to call another function. my problem is with                 document.getElementById('respuesta').value = document.getElementById('respuesta').value + response;

Comment: The `async` property should be set to true, otherwise you will hung the  browser UI. Probably you need to slightly refactor your code. Could you provide the part of code with loop from where you call the above function? In your program is the order of request important? (Is the next request dependent on previous request or they are completely independent and could be send asynchronously?)

Comment: what i want is move a bar every time 1 command is executed and show it with the response of command, but my code shows all response at the same time with progress bar completed (after 2sec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution if anyone is intersting was using a recursive function as next:

```
function cmd(args) {
width = 0;
move(0);
var res = args.split('\n');
var largo = res.length;
var valInit = 0;
if (largo > valInit)
{
    executeCMD(res, valInit);
}
}


function executeCMD(args, i)
{
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ControladorServlet',
                data: {cmd: args[i], operacion: 1, ticket: ticket, iddispositivo: sesion},
                success: function (response) {
                    var textarea = document.getElementById('respuesta');
                    var res = response.trim().split('\n');
                    if(error){//dc}
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById('respuesta').value = document.getElementById('respuesta').value + response.trim() + "\n\n";
                        var valor = (100) * (i + 1) / args.length;
                        move(valor);
                        if (i + 1 < args.length)
                        {
                            executeCMD(args, i + 1);
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'text'
            });
        });
    }
```